# How to undo expand appearence?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I made this vector illustration in Ai but after expanding the appearence there seems to be too many anchor points even double ones so now when I am trying to fill all the objects with colors it won't only the outlines are getting filled, so how can I revert the expand appearence step in order to fill the objects with colors (cmd+G won't work cause I have limited the undone history in system preferences)

Comment: Have you tried using the [Live Paint](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/illustrator/using/live-paint-groups.html) feature in Illustrator to fill your expanded artwork?

Comment: @BillyKerr Nope!

Comment: So is that "nope, but I will try Live Paint", or "nope, it doesn't work"?

Comment: It's nope, but I will try Live Paint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once it was save Ctrl/Command+Z wont work anymore because it is your last instance. If you are not sure to expand it or make it fixed fill you must save an editable back up file. This true to paths with stroke and fill, Texts not Outlined, Stroke Appearance, Brush, Patterrn, Effects etc.

Comment: Good, @Dodie Eslava. I made an action to store a copy in Symbol before I make such undoable changes.

Answer (score 2):

### You can't.

Once you no longer can <kbd>Edit > Undo</kbd> this action, you are out of luck. Illustrator simply doesn't store the necessary data anywhere.

The only option you have is to recreate from scratch.